# Flip table content on select/view with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm an absolute DB/MySQL beginner so I'm not sure if I'm asking the correct questions, but I'd like to give it a try.

I have a Wordpress page set up for a podcast, which is counting the downloads by date within its MySQL database. For keeping track of the downloads I've managed to build a VIEW which looks like this:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| EpisodeID | ReleaseDate | Title | Downloads24h | Downloads7d | Downloads14d |
+-----------+-------------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| 88        | 2018/01/01  | E01   | 83           | 146         | 207          |
| 124       | 2018/01/15  | E02   | 50           | 92          | 156          |
| 172       | 2018/02/15  | E03   | 71           | 100         | 186          |
| 303       | 2020/03/15  | E04   | 92           | 183         | 328          |
+-----------+-------------+-------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
```

Since I'd also like to have some cool charts, I set up ChartJS on my server and tried to use my data from my VIEW but unfortunately it asks for data in columns. That means when I pick up my data from the php side I can only select let's say Downloads24h which ends up as [83,50,71,92] in a line chart which obviously makes no sense.

So what I'd need to do is somehow flip the table to something like this:

```
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Title        | E01 | E02 | E03 | E04 |
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Downloads24h | 83  | 50  | 71  | 92  |
| Downloads7d  | 146 | 92  | 100 | 183 |
| Downloads14d | 207 | 156 | 186 | 328 |
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

As you can see I'm not even dependent on the ID and release date for each episode, since I just need to visualise the numbers with a line graph. I'm thinking about another VIEW which needs to be dynamic, since there are more episodes coming. In the actual table there are over 25 episodes by now, but I watered it down for simplicity.

I'm hoping that there is a super easy solution which I'm just not aware of, maybe even on the php side of things. What I'm doing currently is following:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$Title= '';
$Downloads24H = '';
$Downloads7d = '';
$Downloads14d = '';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `DSI_CAST_STATS_EPISODELIST`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    
$Title= $Title. '"'. $row['Title'].'",';
$Downloads24H = $Downloads24H . '"'. $row['Downloads24H'].'",';
$Downloads7d  = $Downloads7d  . '"'. $row['Downloads7d'].'",';
$Downloads14d = $Downloads14d . '"'. $row['Downloads14d'].'",';
}


$Title= trim($Title,",");
$Downloads24H = trim($Downloads24H,",");
$Downloads7d  = trim($Downloads7d,",");
$Downloads14d = trim($Downloads14d,",");

?>
```

It works but as I stated previously, I'm picking the wrong set of data. Maybe anyone of you magicians has ideas how to fix the whole thing easly. I'd appreciate any tips, tricks or solutions! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use next code to aggregate selected data:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM DSI_CAST_STATS_EPISODELIST;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$data = [
    'Title' => [],
    'Downloads24h' => [],
    'Downloads7d' => [],
    'Downloads14D' => []
];

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data['Title'][] = $row["Title"];
    $data['Downloads24h'][] = $row["Downloads24h"];
    $data['Downloads7d'][] = $row["Downloads7d"];
    $data['Downloads14d'][] = $row["Downloads14d"];
}

var_export($data);
```

Here [live PHP example](https://phpize.online/?phpses=bad9b2f4ba5ce41834c58ba7672b568b&sqlses=9d49926418a6de6edf5045a777d3f689&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)